# Calico: Kubernetes pods can't ping each other use Cluster IP

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, calico

I installed kubernetes using kubeadm v1.14.0 and added two working nodes via the join command.
kubeadm config

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.14.0
controlPlaneEndpoint: "172.22.203.12:6443"
networking:
provider.
    podSubnet: "111.111.0.0/16"
```

node list

```
NAME    STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
linan   Ready    <none>   13h   v1.14.0
node2   Ready    <none>   13h   v1.14.0
yiwu    Ready    master   13h   v1.14.0
```

I checked all pod is bootup

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system

NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-node-h49t9               2/2     Running   1          13h
calico-node-mplwx               2/2     Running   0          13h
calico-node-twvsd               2/2     Running   0          13h
calico-typha-666749994b-d68qg   1/1     Running   0          13h
coredns-8567978547-dhbn4        1/1     Running   0          14h
coredns-8567978547-zv5w5        1/1     Running   0          14h
etcd-yiwu                       1/1     Running   0          13h
kube-apiserver-yiwu             1/1     Running   0          13h
kube-controller-manager-yiwu    1/1     Running   0          13h
kube-proxy-7pjcx                1/1     Running   0          13h
kube-proxy-96d2j                1/1     Running   0          13h
kube-proxy-j5cnw                1/1     Running   0          14h
kube-scheduler-yiwu             1/1     Running   0          13h
```

This is the two pods I used to test usability.

```
kubectl get pods -owide

NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-ds-2br6j   1/1     Running   0          13h   111.111.1.2   linan   <none>           <none>
nginx-ds-t7sfv   1/1     Running   0          13h   111.111.2.2   node2   <none>           <none>
```

but I can't ping pod id from any node(include master) or access the services provided by pod and pod.

```
[root@YiWu ~]# ping 111.111.1.2
PING 111.111.1.2 (111.111.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 111.111.1.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 999ms

[root@YiWu ~]# ping 111.111.2.2
PING 111.111.2.2 (111.111.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 111.111.2.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 999ms
```

> Each node can only access pods on their own host

I checked node calico node log,this log appears on some nodes and some do not.

YiWu

```
bird: BGP: Unexpected connect from unknown address 172.19.0.1 (port 56754)
bird: BGP: Unexpected connect from unknown address 172.19.0.1 (port 40364)
```

node2

```
bird: BGP: Unexpected connect from unknown address 172.22.203.11 (port 57996)
bird: BGP: Unexpected connect from unknown address 172.22.203.11 (port 59485)
```

linan

```
no
```

I install calicoctl check node status in YiWu node

```
DATASTORE_TYPE=kubernetes KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config calicoctl get node -owide

NAME    ASN         IPV4            IPV6   
linan   (unknown)   172.18.0.1/16          
node2   (unknown)   172.20.0.1/16          
yiwu    (unknown)   172.19.0.1/16
```

```
DATASTORE_TYPE=kubernetes KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config calicoctl node status 
Calico process is running.

IPv4 BGP status
+--------------+-------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------------+
| PEER ADDRESS |     PEER TYPE     | STATE |  SINCE   |              INFO              |
+--------------+-------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------------+
| 172.18.0.1   | node-to-node mesh | start | 12:23:15 | Connect                        |
| 172.20.0.1   | node-to-node mesh | start | 12:23:18 | OpenSent Socket: Connection    |
|              |                   |       |          | closed                         |
+--------------+-------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------------+

IPv6 BGP status
No IPv6 peers found.
```

EDIT

```
sysctl -p  /etc/sysctl.d/kubernetes.conf 

net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
vm.swappiness = 0
vm.overcommit_memory = 1
vm.panic_on_oom = 0
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 89100
```

already set ip forward of all node

Comment: "but I can't ping ClusterIP from any node(include master)..." you mean “111.111.1.2”， “111.111.2.2” are ClusterIP? they are Pod IPs. And ClusterIPs in Service are virtual IPs and they can't be pinged. Did you try `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`?

Comment: it return `1`, I already set ip forward right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I restarted calico and checked its log

```sh
kubectl delete-f /etc/kubernetes/addons/calico.yaml
kubectl apply -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/calico.yaml
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
kubectl log calico-node-dp69k -c calico-node -n kube-system
```

> `calico-node-dp69k` is calico node name
>   Check out the calico log and found a strange network card as the boot NIC. like below

```
2019-08-15 04:39:10.859 [INFO][8] startup.go 564: Using autodetected IPv4 address on interface br-b733428777f6: 172.19.0.1/16
```

obviously `br-b733428777f6` is not I expected

I checked [calico configuration doc](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.2/reference/node/configuration) about 
`IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD`

**default calico will use `first-found` mode to select network interface**

> The first-found option enumerates all interface IP addresses and returns the first valid IP address (based on IP version and type of address) on the first valid interface.

In my case, `can-reach` is more suitable for me

so I edit `calico.yaml`, and add `IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD` like this:

```
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  serviceAccountName: calico-node
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
  containers:
    - name: calico-node
      image: quay.io/calico/node:v3.1.3
      env:
        - name: IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD
          value: can-reach=172.22.203.1
```

`can-reach=172.22.203.1` of `172.22.203.1` is gateway ip, then

```sh
kubectl delete-f /etc/kubernetes/addons/calico.yaml
kubectl apply -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/calico.yaml
```

check the log:

```
2019-08-15 04:50:27.942 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 46: Auto-detected address by connecting to remote Destination="172.22.203.1" IP=172.22.203.10

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 55: Checking interface CIDRs Name="cali7b8c9bd2e1f"

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 55: Checking interface CIDRs Name="veth24c7125"

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 55: Checking interface CIDRs Name="br-0b07d34c53b5"

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 57: Checking CIDR CIDR="172.18.0.1/16"

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 55: Checking interface CIDRs Name="tunl0"

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 57: Checking CIDR CIDR="111.111.1.1/32"

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 55: Checking interface CIDRs Name="docker0"

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 57: Checking CIDR CIDR="172.17.0.1/16"

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 55: Checking interface CIDRs Name="enp0s20u1u5"

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 55: Checking interface CIDRs Name="eno4"

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 55: Checking interface CIDRs Name="eno3"

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 55: Checking interface CIDRs Name="eno2"

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 55: Checking interface CIDRs Name="eno1"

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 57: Checking CIDR CIDR="172.22.203.10/24"

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] reachaddr.go 59: Found matching interface CIDR CIDR="172.22.203.10/24"

2019-08-15 04:50:27.943 [INFO][10] startup.go 590: Using autodetected IPv4 address 172.22.203.10/24, detected by connecting to 172.22.203.1
```

wow, it choose right dev interface

go check pod IP is accessible, **Accessable!**

done

Comment: Hi, you mention `172.22.203.1 is gateway ip`. But... what is gateway IP? How can I find it? Thank you.

Comment: route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}'

Answer (score 3):

For future Googler. In my cases,

I used the operator:

```
apiVersion: operator.tigera.io/v1
kind: Installation
metadata:
  name: default
spec:
  # Configures Calico networking.
  calicoNetwork:
    # Note: The ipPools section cannot be modified post-install.
    ipPools:
      - blockSize: 26
        cidr: 10.244.0.0/16 # your pod cidr 
        encapsulation: VXLANCrossSubnet
        natOutgoing: Enabled
        nodeSelector: all()
    nodeAddressAutodetectionV4:
      interface: ens* # Change this one to fix the autodetected issue. My interface is ensxxx
```

And somehow if it doesn't work and it is because you might install flannel, cilium or etc before,

You need to remove the network interface first.

`ip link`

For each interface for flannel, do the following

`ifconfig <name of interface from ip link> down`

`ip link delete <name of interface from ip link>`